# What's a more graceful way to hide private information during a live demo

Tags: display, password

Sometimes I give live demos from my Macbook, whereby I plug in an HDMI cable and show my screen on a projector.

During such demos, I sometimes might need to look up a login password which I keep stored in an encrypted file.

What's a better way besides unplugging the monitor to privately copy this password into the pasteboard without flashing my entire password file on the big screen?

Comment: Use 1password or lastp;ass which won't show the password rather than do your own management

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> which toggles display mirroring. Then use the laptop screen  to do the copy and paste. That way the users still see your main desktop, while you work on your laptop screen.

Comment: This is certainly a useful solution. Also, you could try and freeze the projector if you have the remote for it. That means you no longer see any of the activity on the screen, it just shows the screen you were last on, so your login page.